# How can i justify elements in a row using flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to justify 5 elements in a row using flexbox, padding and justify-content, but i'm getting always a space between the elements.

How can i center them in a row and expanding the padding to the available room?

See https://www.akropolis-ravensburg.de/ *(this is no ad!)* and scroll down to "*Speisekarte*".

You'll see some space between the header elements "*Vorpseisen, Hauptgerichte, Dessert, Mittagskarte, Getränke*" depending on your viewpoint.

Thanks for hints, help and any other. / Alex

Comment: Can you put here the bits of html and css that demonstrate your issue and eventually the desired output to clarify. It Will help you to be helped. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following style rules:

```
nav#nav_speisekarte ul#nav_speisekarte_list li { flex-grow: 1; }
nav#nav_speisekarte ul#nav_speisekarte_list li a { display: block; }
```

The display-inline that was added to the **a**-tags, resulted in the spaces between them. That's a common thing for this type of display. The flex grow on the parent **li**-tag is needed to let them all grow and fill out the space :)